# Use proxy class instead of User for request.user

Tags: django, django-models

I have a meta class for the Django `User` model that I use to add extra methods (overly simplified version):

```
# project.models.pie_lover.py

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class PieLover(User):
    class Meta:
        app_label = "core"
        proxy = True

    def likes_pie(self):
        return True
```

In my view, I wish to get the logged in `PieLover` and see if he likes pie (silly thing to do because a `PieLover` always loves pie, but in a real world situation this may not be the case). My problem lies in the way Django logs in the users, I use the built-in `login(request)` function for this and as a result the object stored in `request.user` is a `User` object, not a `PieLover`.

```
# project.views.like_pie.py

from ..models.pie_lover import PieLover

def index(request):
    pie_lover = request.user

    if pie_lover.likes_pie():
        print "Try pie, try!"
    else:
        print "BLASPHEMER!"
```

If I try to do this Django tells me that the `User` object has no method `likes_pie` which is to be expected as `request.user` is not a `PieLover` instance.

As a quick workaround I just get the `PieLover` which has the same ID as the `User` but that means an extra DB hit.

How can I make Django use `PieLover` by default in the request? 
I was thinking that instead of making another database query to get the proper `PieLover` object to create a new `PieLover` object and pass `request.user` to it at initialization but I don't know what the implications of this are.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After poking around I found, what seems to me, the easiest and non-hackish way to access the `PieLover` methods for a given `User` instance. I have added this to a custom middleware:

```
from models.pie_lover import PieLover

class PieLoverMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        request.pie_lover = PieLover(request.user)
```

Comment: Look into OSQA's Extended User middleware.

Answer (score 1):

How can I make Django use PieLover by default in the request?

> You don't.

Read this before you do anything else: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users

Your "extension" to user should be a separate model with all of your extension methods in that separate model.

You can then navigate from User (in the request) to your extension trivially using the `get_profile()` method already provided.

Comment: S.Lott the OP is not talking about adding extra fields to his model, just a few methods. I think the best approach would be monkeypatching lik @Ronnie or using a custom AuthenticationMiddleware

Comment: @armonge: "is not talking about adding extra fields to his model".  You're sure?  My experience is that all such "additions" to the User class involve data.  This may be the rare exception.  I would still suggest that the built-in, supported extension mechanism is always best.

Comment: @S.Lott: Nope, just needed to add some methods, I don't have extra data. And even if that were the case, it would be a bit weird having to write request.user.get_profile().some_new_method() when I could just as easily write request.user.pie_lover.some_new_method()

Comment: I'm not sure why `pie_lover` is so nice and `get_profile()` is so bad.  But.  There's a readily available, default, supported, easy-to-use mechanism already built for you.  It requires much less thinking.

Comment: @yoshi why would it be request.user.pie_lover.some_new_method() instead of request.user.some_new_method() ?

Comment: @armonge Oops, that was a typo. Guess I was tired. It was supposed to be `request.pie_lover.some_new_method`

Comment: @S.Lott: this lets him modify the python behavior of the model without having to store another table and do an additional DB lookup every time (although this will happen anyway if he's using regular django.contrib.auth). If it's just a proxy model, why not. Just use a middleware to set request.user.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib.auth import models as auth_models

def _my_func(self):
    return True

auth_models.User.my_func = _my_func
```